# Tell Nginx to look for my theme files in a different directory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a normal WordPress website with root at `/var/www/example.com/public`.

I want my theme files which would normally be located at `/var/www/example.com/public/wp-content/themes/mytheme/` to actually be located at `/home/ubuntu/my-github-repo/mytheme/` so that I can keep developing my theme files separately from the rest of the website files.

Any idea how I would achieve this? I initially thought I could do it with a symlink if I set  `disable_symlinks off;` in my `nginx.conf` but that didn't seem to work.

I then tried to use a location block like so:

```
...
root /var/www/example.com/public;

location ~* ^/wp-content/themes/mytheme.+\.(php)$ {
    root /home/ubuntu/my-github-repo/mytheme/;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

location ~* ^/wp-content/themes/mytheme.+\.(!php)$ {
    root /home/ubuntu/my-github-repo/mytheme/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
...
```

My Nginx user is `www-data` and it has permission to read the repo directory.

I am looking for the simplest way to implement this so I can keep my repos organized and away from my web files.

As an aside, this is all running locally, so security is not a major consideration.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `www-data` would need permission to read `home`, `ubuntu`, `my-github-repo`, `mytheme` and the files within. I don't know why symlinks wouldn't work, unless its a permissions problem.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Parent directory did not have correct permissions.